# A String of graphemes

Tags: terminology

What you name a string of glyphs (letters) regardless of their meaning and regardless of their pronunciation?

for example in Persian ‍‍`س`+`ی`+`ر`  = `س‌ی‌ر` represents following words (and more):

1. `/siɾ/`  garlic
2. `/siɾ/`  a unit of weight (75g)
3. `/sejɾ/` travel

These words are homonyms or heteronyms, or in English `moped`=`m+o+p+e+d`:

1. moped   /ˈmoʊpɛd/   n.  a small motorcycle
2. moped       /ˈmoʊpt/    v.  past tense of mope

What you name `moped` and `س‌ی‌ر`:  some letters that are written representation of one or more morpheme?

**Update**: to clarify what I am looking consider following table, what you name first column?

```
 (?)     number of words
------  ----------------
moped          2
dog            1
does           3
```

**Update 2:** In languages that are written use Arabic script short vowel generally are not written, as a result most strings represent more than one word.

Comment: Characters? .....

Comment: So what you mean is a continuous stroke? I don't quite understand.

Comment: @Cerberus I need two words to fill these blankets: `"سیر is a ... for that three words."` and  `"سیر have three ...".`

Comment: Aren't Persian and Arabic letters just called letters? If not letters, then I would call them characters. But I think we call them letters: it is after all an alphabet. The fact that they are written attached in words doesn't change that: the Latin, Greek, and Cyrillic alphabets can also be written attached. If words can be attached without spaces in Persian, I could call the result long words, compound words, or phrases, or sentences, depending on their function. What does سیر  mean? Are those elements like ر letters? I would think so?

Comment: It's an abjad, not quite an alphabet. Only the consonants are represented, and there are clues to the vowels which are optionally deleted, in idiosyncratic random ways, by variable social conventions. That's why there's no exact relationship between the characters and the phonemics; _phoneme_ is a concept that depends on an alphabet, not an abjad like Arabic or an abugida like Devanagari.

Comment: An orthographic word?

Comment: @jlawler: Yes, okay, I knew they usually did not write vowels. But I believe one calls the elements letters and the entities between spaces words? I have never seen them described otherwise in Persian, not even by this Persian guy I know, with whom we read Persian poems once (he recited them, we read the translation + translitteration, and then we discussed them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Colin Fine said **Word form** is probably most related term. But I decide to use **string** because convey exactly just what I mean, also in computer programming a string of letters are called string.

Answer (score 0):

[Homograph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homograph). Literally "same spelling". Any two words with different meanings which are spelled the same regardless of their pronunciation (it could be the same or it could be different. It doesn't matter).

Taking the discussion of abjad to it's logical conclusion, I see no reason why this term couldn't be extended to even completely non-phonetic writing systems. I can easily imagine some Chinese-like ideograph which represents two separate concepts (perhaps with the same pronunciation or not). Since they are orthographically identical I'd still consider them homographs.

Comment: Thanks for your note, But it is not what I am looking for.

Comment: @PHPist I've looked at your clarification. Honestly, the word I'd use is just "word" (or as Colin Fine suggested, "form"). If you want some word that denotes it has multiple senses, then maybe "homographic word/form". Addressing one of the comments you left on your original question, I'd write: "سیر is a homograph for these three senses." and "سیر has three senses". I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, it is not a concept that has been discussed enough to have a customary term. If I were writing about it, I would use *word form*.